# Device farm interactive testing done programmatically

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, ui-testing, aws-device-farm, firebase-test-lab

AWS has a 'remote-desktopy' feature (https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/aws-device-farm-update-remote-access-to-devices-for-interactive-testing/) as part of its device farm, but it is far too slow to use in browser. Does anyone know if there is a programmatic/CLI way to interact with that system?

I would like to test the functionality of a third party app on a cloud based mobile testing platform such as Firebase Test Lab, or AWS device farm. I have no way to instrument this app.
The testing requires I download two apps on the device (one is the app to be tested, the second has a supporting function). At the start of the test I have to launch the support app, and then switch over to the app I am testing. I imagine the only way to do this is via the device's 'home' button. The actual testing is just a set of basic UI interactions.

Does the Firebase Test lab or other platform have a feature that I could use to do this?

If there was a way to extract events from the AWS remote-desktop, I could see an approach using a selenium/other webdriver. But I am not sure this a real option.

Any thoughts on this are appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: You could automate this using a testing framework. Have you looked at the auxiliary app feature of device farm yet? It installs additional apps in the device that you upload.

Answer (score 0):

"The UI Automator APIs allow you to write robust tests without needing to know about the implementation details of the app that you are targeting. You can use these APIs to capture and manipulate UI components across multiple apps" ([documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/ui-automator#ui-automator-apis))

To tap the Home button you can use [UiDevice.pressHome()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/uiautomator/UiDevice#presshome).